# Deleting emails from Office 365 Groups

Tags: office365, exchangewebservices

Does anyone know if it is possible to use EWs with C# or Powershell or any other option to delete emails from an Office 365 Group.

We have a very heavily used group that frequently gets full.  At present we have to manually delete using Outlook which takes an age.

Tried an Office 365 retention delete policy but it doesn't seem to want to delete the emails.

Any one got any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of the [`Item.Delete`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.item.delete?view=exchange-ews-api) method of EWS.

Below is an example of deleting items from a Junk email folder. You should change the 
[`WellKnownFolderName`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.wellknownfoldername?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=exchange-ews-api) property to whatever folder you wish to delete the items from.
You may also wish to increase the [`pageSize`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.pagedview.pagesize?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=exchange-ews-api#Microsoft_Exchange_WebServices_Data_PagedView_PageSize) property to something more appropriate to your needs.

```
private void JunkEmailCleanup()
{
    // Connect to the Exchange web service.
    ExchangeService service = new ExchangeService(ExchangeVersion.Exchange2013_SP1);
    service.Credentials = new WebCredentials(Account_UserName, Account_Password, Account_Domain);
    service.Url = new Uri(Service_URL);

    // Set the page size.
    const int pageSize = 20;
    // Set the ItemView with the page size.
    ItemView view = new ItemView(pageSize);
    // Indicate that the base property will be the item identifier.
    view.PropertySet = new PropertySet(BasePropertySet.IdOnly);

    FindItemsResults<Item> findResults = service.FindItems(WellKnownFolderName.JunkEmail, view);

    if (findResults != null)
    {
        foreach (EmailMessage item in findResults)
        {
            item.Delete(DeleteMode.HardDelete, true);
        }
    }
}
```

This article may also be useful to you: [Deleting items by using EWS in Exchange](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/client-developer/exchange-web-services/deleting-items-by-using-ews-in-exchange)